# Does small talk not build relationship and is it not great for our happiness levels?

Tags: psychology, sociology

I'm referencing this article: http://www.wired.co.uk/article/banning-small-talk

> research has confirmed what most people know but don't practice:
>   surface level small talk does not build relationships and it is not
>   great for our happiness levels. The obvious question: if it's not that
>   good for us, why does it prevail?

and

> According to a 2010 study by social anthropologist Kate Fox, in
>   Britain, more than nine in ten people admit to having talked about the
>   weather in the last six hours. Around 38 per cent say they've talked
>   about it in the past hour.

Is this representation of the research correct? Does the research paper represent current consensus on the matter?

Comment: If you start with "What exactly is the definition of small talk" the question isn't about a well-defined empiric question.
I also see no reason why happiness and relationships should be bundled into one question.

Comment: @Christian the thing is there seems to be a relationship: a person is probably happier if their relationships are better, I am curious if the study took it into consideration.